# React can not access variable from return

Tags: reactjs

[image][image]I am very new to React and I can not solve this issue for a very long time. The idea is the following, I get some user info from database and pass it into cookies. From react side I get this cookies as JSON object and I need to render menu for user depending on values in this object. Right now I pass this object that I get from cookies from parent Component and I try to access it from Settings component. The issue is that I can see access this object from test function, however when I try to access this data from return it gives me undefined error. The function that returns value from cookies is sync, I have no idea why that might happen, please help.....[image]

Comment: In `test` function you are accesing `this.state.shopSetting` whereas in your component, you are accessing `this.state.shopSettings` (with an extra S at the end). What's weird is that `test` should log undefined.

Comment: I made a typo before making screenshot, it should be **this.state.shopSettings** in **test**, so no issues on that

Comment: Okey, what's the value of `this.state.shopSettings` if you console.log it in the `render()` function? It's possible that 'new_orders' key does not exist in the object.

Comment: When I call **console.log(this.state.shopSettings)** where **enabled** is defined I get expected object, new_orders is present in keys

Comment: Also it logs it two times, maybe that could help...

Comment: I can't see the connection between `enabled` and `this.state.shopSettings` in the snippet you posted.

Comment: There is no connection between them for now, but **this.state.shopSettings['new_orders']** has only true/false values

Comment: If I do **console.log(this.state.shopSettings['new_orders'])** in render it also returns undefined, but without **new_orders** I see whole object with new_orders key, that is too strange

Answer (score 2):

1. Since `this.state.shopSettings["new_orders"]` is boolean, use ternary.
2. Don't copy props to the state inside constructor as the constructor is executed only once. So updates to the props won't be reflected in the component.

**Like this**

```js
<button onClick={this.test}>
  {props.shopSettings && (props.shopSettings["new_orders"] ? 'true button' : 'false button')}
</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately did not help, it seems that this code overloaded my computer and browser, it became very laggy. Dont know why that happened. I get them as object for 100% since I use Cookies.getJSON

Comment: ok - try `{this.state.shopSettings && this.state.shopSettings)["new_orders"]}` in the `<button>` ... if it doesn't work , then  share the output of console.log ... also share more code if possible

Comment: Did not work, I have attached output of **console.log(this.state.shopSettings)** inside render. Also if try **console.log(this.state.shopSettings['new_orders'])** I get undefined

Comment: Also send project structure and component which gives this variable

Comment: This works as expected! Thank you, but  is it possible to access this variables somehow? I will need to change them if user clicks on a button and so on, maybe there is better solution than cookies? I can build an api but I have questions about authentications, I run everything using next and koa right now

Answer (score 0):

It solves very easily with this code, now I can access any key from shopSettings inside return without any issues

```html
class Index extends React.Component {
    state = {
        shopSettings: Cookies.getJSON('shopSettings')
    }

    render() {
        const {shopSettings} = this.state

        if (!shopSettings) {
            return null
        }
        
        return (
          <div>Hello</div>
        )
    }
```